# Unslider multiple slides with every click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, unslider

I am trying to get the jquery plugin [unslider](http://unslider.com/) working where on every click of the next/previous button, the next couple hidden slides move into view.

For example, if on page load only three slides are in view, then every time the next arrow is clicked, the next three slides come in to view.

I currently have unslider working where only one slide is in view and one slide moves into view with every click.

Was wondering if anyone had accomplished this behavior in the past with this plugin and was willing to assist?

Thanks in advance

JS

```
$('.photo-slider').unslider({
    infinite: true,
    nav: false
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="photo-slider">
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        Hello1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello3
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello4
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello5
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello6
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello7
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello8
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello9
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello10
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello11
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello12
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello13
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello14
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Hello15
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better change view and add 3 image or text in one li, like this:

```
<div class="photo-slider">
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div>Hello1</div>
                    <div>Hello2</div>
                    <div>Hello3</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>Hello4</div>
                    <div>Hello5</div>
                    <div>Hello6</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr, this may work for a static screen size, but what about fluid-designs?

Comment: use flex content https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I also have the same requirement of showing multiple slides on every click just like bxSlider and slickslide. Is there any option that we could achieve using unslider config options? My requirement is to show one slide per click in mobile and show 3 per click in desktop. Is this possible?I will not be able to change the template as you have suggested.